# What is the ideal database that allows fast cosine distance?

Tags: feature-extraction, databases

I'm currently trying to store many feature vectors in a database so that, upon request, I can compare an incoming feature vector against many other (if not all) stored in the db. I would need to compute the Cosine Distance and only return, for example, the first 10 closest matches. Such vector will be of size ~1000 or so.

Every request will have a feature vector and will need to run a comparison against all feature vectors belonging to a subset within the db (which will most likely be in the order of thousands of entries per subset in the worst case scenario).

Which database offers the flexibility to run such a query efficiently ?

I looked into postgres but I was wondering if there were alternatives that better fit this problem. Not sure it matters much, but I'm most likely going to be using Python.

I found [this](https://sciencesql.blogspot.com/2016/03/calculating-cosine-similarity-between.html) article about doing it in SQL.

**EDIT:** I am open to alternative solutions for this problem that are not necessarily tied to SQL.

Comment: How large is your dataset? Is it possible to precompute the cosine similarity between every vector and store that instead (or in addition)?

Comment: I will edit the question, the database won't be too big (talking about thousands of entries). The problem is that I don't care about the similarity between one another but I will submit a request with an unseen feature vector and I will have to compute the similarity against a subset of feature vectors (already in the db) and return the closest ones. Not sure I explained myself as well as I think, so let me know if it's still not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's only a few thousand entries each with a 1,000 features, you may just be able to keep it in RAM if you are running this on some kind of server. Then when you get a new feature vector, just run cosine similarity routine. An easy way to do this is just use something standard like pandas and scikit-learn.

Alternatively you can keep everything in SQL, load it into something like pandas and use scikit-learn.

I'm actually not sure you'll get much of a speed up, if any, by writing the computation in SQL itself.

Comment: Nice thank you, I thought for some reason there existed a db implementation optimized for these kind of tasks. Now out of curiosity, what if the entries grow by an order of magnitude ?

Comment: I think you just have to try a couple of options and benchmark for your use case. If you have double precision numbers and 10,000 vectors with 1,000 features each, that's about 80 MB plus overhead for whatever data structure you might be using (like a pandas dataframe). Should be doable to store in RAM for most systems. But that use case is for a server where you load it once at server startup.

Comment: Oh nice, loading it once at startup time sounds like the way to go, I think that can help share the allocated memory for different requests as well. So I load them at startup and they can be accessed at any time from any request, at that point it will be more computation than anything, I think I have a pretty good idea on how to limit memory usage. Thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: Please be sure to mark this as the accepted answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to scale beyond 1000 entries in the future, a brute-force approach to find the exact neighbors will become increasingly prohibitive from a computational standpoint. To future-proof your solution, I would recommend looking into the well-researched field of approximate nearest neighbors (ANN) techniques. Obviously there is a speed/accuracy tradeoff, but as of this writing, there is really no other way to scale your search to millions or billions of entries.

The big tech companies rely almost exclusively on techniques like these. Think about...

- Facebook querying similar faces to suggest people to tag in your photos
- Spotify recommending semantically similar songs
- Google searching images similar to one you uploaded

This [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/comprehensive-guide-to-approximate-nearest-neighbors-algorithms-8b94f057d6b6) is an excellent overview of current state-of-the-art algorithms along with their pros and cons. Below, I've linked several popular open-source implementations. All 3 have Python bindings

- Facebook [FAISS](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss)
- Spotify [Annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy)
- Google [ScaNN](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/scann)

Answer (score 2):

If you are afraid that the dataset is big that a regular database might not handle it, you could consider an alternative implementation such as [SimHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimHash).

From Wikipedia,

> In computer science, SimHash is a technique for quickly estimating how
>   similar two sets are. The algorithm is used by the Google Crawler to
>   find near duplicate pages. It was created by Moses Charikar.

Here is the [research paper](http://www.wwwconference.org/www2007/papers/paper215.pdf) from Google and here several implementations in [Python](https://www.google.com/search?q=simhash%20python&oq=simhash%20python&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3151j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it and see if it fits my case.

Answer (score 2):

A brute force approach has O(n) search complexity no matter if you do it in Python or a database. For faster queries you need a tree-structured multidimensional lookup table, for example, a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). For Python, there are implementations of a k-d tree in both **SciPy** and **Scikit-Learn**:

- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html
- https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html

If you need a standalone database solution, see:

- PostgreSQL with [Cube](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/cube.html) extension supplemented with a GIST index created on a table for fast vector queries, details: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/163915/177276
- ElasticSearch with its [cosineSimilarity](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/query-dsl-script-score-query.html#vector-functions) function, read more [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch); possibly extended with this [plugin](https://github.com/lior-k/fast-elasticsearch-vector-scoring) for speedup - although both perform an exhaustive search.
- A dedicated DB solution for vector similarity search, like [AquilaDB](https://github.com/Aquila-Network/AquilaDB) that utilizes Facebook's [FAISS](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss) and Spotify's [Annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy) libraries internally.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is there a reason why you need to do this in SQL? Most architecture patterns would advise against keeping formulas and logic in the database layer. Why not create another layer - outside the database - with a language that can do the computations you need?
2. You can also do the calculations ahead of time and store them in a cached lookup table on the database. Do all the computations you need and then import them into your database and then just run standard SQL SELECT statements to pull the results at run-time.

Comment: Well I would do that but the comparison will be between a subset of feature vectors in the db against an unseen feature vector. So I can do some math ahead of time, but the final distance will need to be computed for every request. I hope it makes sense, let me know if you need more clarity.

Comment: @G4bri3l OK, so maybe the second option is out. But the first option is still valid. You really should try to avoid having logic in SQL - the database should be your repository, not a computational engine.

Comment: That makes sense absolutely, as you can guess I'm a bit new to these kind of problems so, how should I go about this? I feel like I'm trying to find a solution within the realm of what I know, I'm just not very aware of possible approaches for this type of problems.

Comment: @G4bri3l When you say that you receive a "request", how exactly is that coming in to you? Is that a physical request? Or some sort of automated system? What you want to do is introduce a new layer that sits in between your request system and your database. Let's assume that it's a python script. The inputs to the script would be whatever is provided by the request. Then let python do the database querying for the remaining outputs and then have a function that does the calculation you need. The python output should be your final result that sends it back to the request and the process moves on

Comment: Trying to keep it simple, a request is sent to an API, this API sends a request to another service and gets back a feature vector. Now this feature vector needs to be compared to a subset of feature vectors in a db so that I can return the closest match. If I am understanding this right, I might as well request the subset of feature vectors I need and then just let the server do the comparison using its own memory. So the API is the one doing the comparison and I don't do it on the data layer.

Answer (score 0):

See:
[Vector Similarity Search with Azure SQL database and OpenAI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/vector-similarity-search-with-azure-sql-database-and-openai/)

```
/*
    From GitHub project: Azure-Samples/azure-sql-db-openai
*/
ALTER   function [dbo].[SimilarContentArticles](@vector nvarchar(max))
returns table
as
return with cteVector as
(
    select 
        cast([key] as int) as [vector_value_id],
        cast([value] as float) as [vector_value]
    from 
        openjson(@vector)
),
cteSimilar as
(
select top (5)
    v2.ArticleDetailId, 
    sum(v1.[vector_value] * v2.[vector_value]) / 
        (
            sqrt(sum(v1.[vector_value] * v1.[vector_value])) 
            * 
            sqrt(sum(v2.[vector_value] * v2.[vector_value]))
        ) as cosine_distance
from 
    cteVector v1
inner join 
    dbo.ArticleVectorData v2 on v1.vector_value_id = v2.vector_value_id
group by
    v2.ArticleDetailId
order by
    cosine_distance desc
)
select 
    (select [ArticleName] from [Article] where id = a.ArticleId) as ArticleName,
    a.ArticleContent,
    a.ArticleSequence,
    r.cosine_distance
from 
    cteSimilar r
inner join 
    dbo.[ArticleDetail] a on r.ArticleDetailId = a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

would be one that uses an inverted index and stores the vectors in a compact format such as sparse vectors or quantized vectors.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/87838)